# Typescript Error ts(2345): Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Folder'.(vue3 compositionAPI)

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am trying to pass props from parent component to child in Vue.js.

In the parent component,

```html
<template>
  <child v-for="(folder, idx) in folders" :key="idx" :folder="folder">

  </child>
</template>


<script lang="ts">
import {ref, defineComponent} from "vue";
import Child from "../components/Child.vue";
interface Folder {
    id: number,
    name: string | null,
}
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Parent",
  components: {Child},
  setup(){
    const folders = ref<Folder[]>()

    folders.value = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "aaa"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "bbb"
      }
    ]

    return {folders}
  }
})
```

In the child component,

```html
<template>
    <p>{{folder.name}}</p>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent} from "vue";
interface Folder {
    id: number,
    name: string | null,
}

export default defineComponent({
    name: "Child",
    props:{
        folder:  Object as PropType<Folder>,
    },
    setup(){
        return {}
    }
})
```

With the following error code I get

> Argument of type 'Folder | undefined' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'Folder'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type
> 'Folder'.ts(2345)

How to solve this error?

Comment: Where exactly is the error? The question may not contain the code that causes it. In the code you posted there are no values with `Folder | undefined` type so far

Comment: The error is In the child component html

Comment: I'm getting "undefined" in the error even though I'm not using "undefined" in the interface.  It's strange.

Comment: I believe all props are `Type | undefined` by default unless you also set `required: true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the props section of your code with the following:

```
   props: {
     folder: {
       type: Object as PropType<Folder>,
       required: true,
     }
   },
```

This way `undefined` will not be considered as an option to be assigned to the **Folder** type.

This happens because all props are optional, and an absent optional prop will have `undefined` value according to the docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-validation